# PHP: Namespaced classes, class loading and exceptions causes weird behaviour

Tags: php, debugging, exception, namespaces

I witnessed some strange behaviour regarding PHP's exception handling in a recent project. Case goes as follows.

In my app, I use namespaces. All classes are in individual source code files. The code relevant to this particular case, is spread over 3 classes.

The "outermost" class is a dispatcher (or router), which wraps the dispatch call inside a try-catch block. The dispatched request, calls a method in a third class, which runs code (wrapped in a try-catch block), which causes an exception.

Because I had omitted a `use Exception;` statement in the class where the error happens, the thrown exception trickles all the way back to the outermost layer (the dispatcher), where it is caught - causing me to scratch my head why the catch around the code causing the error isn't working.

To me this seems strange. Logically, PHP should in this situation (IMO) throw a `Class not found` exception/error, leading me to the actual error in my code, instead of trying to "stay alive" as long as possible.

Should this be filed as a bug, or is this expected behaviour?

Edit: Code example

File: `class-a.php`

```
<?php 
namespace hello\world;

class classA {
    protected $b;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new \hello\world\classB();
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        try {
            $this->b->throwException();
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

File: `class-b.php`

```
<?php 
namespace hello\world;

class classB
{
    public function throwException() {
        throw new \Exception("bar closed");
    }
}
```

File: `run.php`

```
<?php 
include 'class-a.php';
include 'class-b.php';

$a = new \hello\world\classA();

$a->doSomething();
```

ClassB `throw`s an `\Exception` in `ClassB::doSomething()`, for which `ClassA` has a `catch`-clause, but because `ClassA` doesn't declare `use Exception` or `catch (\Exception)`, the `catch` doesn't match and execution ends with a `Uncaught exception` error<sup>1</sup>. But in my opinion, it should cause a `Class not found` error.

I might be expecting too much of the permissive PHP compiler, but it would help in tracking down silly errors that should be easy for the compiler to spot.

<sup>1</sup> If the `$a->doSomething()` in `run.php` was surrounded by a `try..catch` clause, the `Exception` would (or at least could) be caught there, since it trickles down the stack.

Comment: please attach a small code sample

Comment: Same described in comments: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#99702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's exception catching mechanism does not validate that the class you catch actually exists.

It exhibits the same behavior when using typehinting in functions, so I suspect it merely converts the exception/function type hint into a string or something and compares that with the type of the relevant object.

Whether this is a bug or not is questionable. Personally I think it should be classified as a bug, but PHP has all sorts of wonky behaviors :D

Comment: Indeed, but with typehinting, I get the "class not found" error if I leave out the correct `use` in the class. Perhaps I would in this case, too, if I didn't have the "super-catch" lower in the stack. Got to do more research, maybe.

Comment: This is expected behavior. As those classes can be not loaded yet.

Comment: My suspicions were incorrect. Removing the "super-catch" does not result in a `Class not found`. Apparently, the `throw` construct gets special treatment. Go figure.

Comment: The reason `throw new Foo` causes a class not found is because you are actually trying to create a new instance of the class there. That differs somewhat from just having a type hint

Comment: @Xerxus argument makes sense to me.

Comment: @Jani: No, it doesn't, which is what baffled me in the first place. Forget the type hint comment altogether. What I really meant was, if I try to say `new FooClass` without `use`ing it first, I will get a `Class not found` error, but `throw`ing a `new Exception` will only result in a `Uncaught exception`, or it being caught lower down the stack (where `Exception` is known).

Comment: @nikc I don't really know.. I tried this: `namespace Hello\World; throw new Exception();` and I received `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Hello\World\Exception' not found`. I also tried a slightly more complicated one, where there was a catch block in non-namespaced code and it still caused that error to be triggered.

Comment: @Jani: yes, you are right. And also, my explanation was flawed. I revised my question with a working example.